# Advancing the ticks at the beginning of the plot

Tags: netlogo

I want to know whether if it's possible to begin a plot with a certain number of ticks passed, i.e 60 instead of 0.
For the model I have created, I begin with 60 ticks (when I click the go procedure for the first time my ticks increment from 60 to 61 and then ever next click it increments by 1 (i.e 62,63,64 and so on). I have done this by using the advanced-ticks function in my setup procedure so that the ticks will begin at 60.

```
to setup
...
advanced-ticks 60
end

to go
...
end
```

But when I look at my plots this is not reflected, they instead start plotting from 0. Is there a way to make my plots begin at 60.

Answer (score 2):

The key primitive for doing this is [`plotxy`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#plotxy).

A common usage pattern for `plotxy` is:

```
plotxy ticks y
```

where `y` is whatever you want to plot.

Your particular case is a little bit more tricky, however, because you're trying to advance the tick counter before plotting.

I would suggest using the following pattern:

```
to setup
  clear-all
  ; ...general setup code here...
  reset-ticks
  tick-advance 60
  update-plots
end
```

And then setting up your plot like this:

[image]

(We're plotting `random 100` here, but it's just an example. Replace that with what you want.)

The key thing to understand is that [`reset-ticks`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#reset-ticks) always updates the plots in addition to setting the ticks counter to zero. But we don't want to plot the state at tick zero, so we need `if ticks > 0` in the pen update commands. What we *do* want, however, is to plot the state at tick 60, so we need to call [`update-plots`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#update-plots) after advancing the tick counter.

Also notice that we change the "X min" property of the plot to 60 in order not to leave a blank space on the left of the plot. You can set "X max" to whatever you want and "Auto scale" should take care of the rest.

You don't need to do anything special in your `go` procedure. All the rest should proceed as normal...